# How to prevent a View from loading multiple times after the first call?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

When I open "EditAwardsView1" for the first time the Window.alert displays once. I enter data, select the "Save" button and my save to the DB occurs once. So far so good.

However, I then go back to the previous view "SelectPerson" and then open "EditAwardsView1" a second time. This time Window.alert displays twice and I get one "Uncaught exception escaped" error. I enter data, select the "Save" button and my save to the DB occurs twice.

If I repeat this again (go back to "SelectPerson" and then back to "EditAwardsView1") Window.alert displays five times and I get four "Uncaught exception escaped" errors. I enter data, select the "Save" button and my save to the DB occurs five times.

The calling code from the "SelectPerson" view is:

```
btnEditAward.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        navHandler2.go("EditAwards1");
    }
});
btnEditAward.setStyleName("gwt-PushButton-up");
btnEditAward.setText("Edit Awards");
btnEditAward.setWidth("184px");
btnEditAward.setHeight("40px");
horizontalPanel.add(btnEditAward);
```

The entry point in "EditAwards1" is:

```
public EditAwardsView1(final NavHandler navHandler) {

    rpc = (DBConnectionAsync) GWT.create(DBConnection.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpc;
    String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "MySQLConnection";
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

    navHandler2 = navHandler;

    //On load of page get the stored view data
    //TODO Fix null pointer on reload.
    verticalPanel.addAttachHandler(new Handler() {
        int pog = 0;
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            if (pog == 0) {
                pog++;
                verticalPanel.clear();
                listBoxAwardType.clear();
                awardGrouped = null;
                Window.alert("EditAwardsView1.");

                //Retrieve stored data for this view.                   
                AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback = new ViewDataHandler2<ViewData>(EditAwardsView1.this);
                rpc.getViewData(callback);

            }else{
                pog = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    initWidget(verticalPanel);
}
```

The calling code from "EditAwardsView1" to return to the "SelectPerson" view is:

```
//Button btnSelectYouthMember = new Button("Select Youth Member");
        btnSelectYouthMember.setStyleName("gwt-PushButton-up");
        btnSelectYouthMember.setText("Select Youth Member");
        btnSelectYouthMember.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                navHandler2.go("SelectPerson");
            }
        });
        btnSelectYouthMember.setWidth("184px");
        btnSelectYouthMember.setHeight("40px");
        horizontalPanel_Menu.add(btnSelectYouthMember);
```

The error is:

```
[ERROR] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] - Uncaught exception escaped


15:58:18.009 [ERROR] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] Uncaught exception escaped

com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(12426), JavaScript object(2059), JavaScript object(12432)]): Unable to set property 'onfocus' of undefined or null reference
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:299)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.alert(Window.java)
at org.AwardTracker.client.EditAwardsView1$3.onAttachOrDetach(EditAwardsView1.java:131)
at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.AttachEvent.dispatch(AttachEvent.java:100)
at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.AttachEvent.dispatch(AttachEvent.java:1)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.AttachEvent.fire(AttachEvent.java:52)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:351)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.onAttach(Composite.java:162)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.setParent(Widget.java:475)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.adopt(Panel.java:127)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel.add(ComplexPanel.java:97)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel.add(AbsolutePanel.java:97)
at org.AwardTracker.client.NavHandler.go(NavHandler.java:53)
at org.AwardTracker.client.SelectPersonView$ViewDataHandler$2.onClick(SelectPersonView.java:131)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:56)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: How are you "going back"?  I can't quite see why you are using the attach event. Can't you just do this in the constructor? It might keep the code simpler to just use each instance view once then throw it away?

Comment: @salk31 the attach event goes off when something is actually added to the dom, in this case its almost certainly `horizontalPanel_Menu.add(btnSelectYouthMember)`. However when the event handler goes off, it looks like the *alert* is causing the exception, which really doesn't make any sense. Is this by any chance specific to a certain browser?

Comment: Hi salk31, I am going back by clicking on a button. Please see "The calling code from "EditAwardsView1" to return to the "SelectPerson" view is:" above. I have added another Window.alert in the first view and when I return to the first view it seems that another instance of the view is created as it displays twice. How do I trow away the first instance of the view please. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Hi salk31 and Colin, So the sequence of events are: From "SelectYouthMember" I select a menu button to open "EditAwards1", an alert in that click handler informs me that I have selected "EditAwards1", "EditAwards1" opens and an alert in the AttachHandler informs me that it is attached. I then perform some tasks culminating in selecting a menu button to go back to "SelectYouthMember". "SelectYouthMember" view is opened.

Comment: I then perform some tasks in "SelectYouthMember" culminating in selecting a menu button to go back to "EditAwards1" an alert in that click handler informs me that I have selected "EditAwards1", "EditAwards1" opens and an alert in the AttachHandler informs me that it is attached. This is the interesting part: once again an alert in that click handler informs me that I have selected "EditAwards1" and an alert in the AttachHandler informs me that it is attached.

Comment: From this I surmise that "SelectPerson" view is created a second time when I return to it from "EditAwards1". Both versions of the view react to commands and therefore when I go back to "EditAwards1" two more "EditAwards1" views are created.

Comment: I further surmise that I need to "dispose" of each view when I exit and not leave it "lying around". Is this correct and how do I "dispose" of a view on exit? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: P.s., I believe the exception is being caused by the extra views that are being generated and once I fix the multiple view generation issue the exception will also be resolved. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: I was mainly asking why you are using the attach event. This seems odd usage. Can't you just do it in the constructor of the UI Widget? Throwing away the view is just making sure it is not reachable although you may still have async events pending... If you care you can do isAttached to avoid doing any work for a thrown away widget.

Comment: Hi salk31, the short answer is - because this is how I was advised to do it in a reply to another question. Can you please provide a sample of an alternative way of doing this please. I have been thinking about this and reading up on it. My guess is that once I have created the page once then I need to set a flag so I do not create the widgets on it again. Each time I enter I just need to empty (clear) the data. I will try this. Thanks for your help. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=2265752 for an answer.

In short I: 
deleted NavHandler.java, 
changed AwardTracker.java to allow for history and remove need for  NavHandler.java, 
changed new view call to History.newItem("selectPerson", true); 
added the test if (event.isAttached()) to the AttachHandler and 
moved the following code into the AttachHandler - 
    rpc = (DBConnectionAsync) GWT.create(DBConnection.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpc;
    String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "MySQLConnection";
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

Regards,

Glyn